# domains have some common fields,extends domain or embedded?

Tags: grails, dns, domain-driven-design, grails-orm

when i design database.I use embedded to embed common fields.but it's can't init dateCreated and createdBy,what'd i do?extends domain or embedded is right way to handle common fields?
code to say?

```
    class Created {
      Date dateCreated
      Long createdBy
        def beforeInsert()
            {
             dateCreated= new Date()
             createdBy=0
        }
   }

class Updated {

Date lastUpdated
Long updatedBy

//it works?
def beforeUpdate(){
    lastUpdated=new Date()
    updatedBy=0
}
//it works?
def beforeInsert(){
    lastUpdated=new Date()
    updatedBy=0
}
}


class CreatedUpdated {

Created created

Updated updated

//Must use the embedded option, or the type of exception, can not find CreatedUpdated
static embedded = ['created','updated']
}

class Term {

String name

CreatedUpdated createdUpdated

static embedded = ['createdUpdated']

    Term parent

    static hasMany =[terms:Term]

    static mapping = {
        version false
   }

   String toString()
  {
    name
  }

static constraints = {
    name unique:true,size: 1..20
    parent nullable: true  
    createdUpdated display:false,nullable:true
    terms display:false
    url url: true
}
   }
```

or use extends?

```
   class Term extends CreatedUpdated{
    String name

    Term parent

    static hasMany =[terms:Term]

    static mapping = {
        version false
   }

   String toString()
  {
    name
  }

static constraints = {
    name unique:true,size: 1..20
    parent nullable: true  
    terms display:false
    url url: true
}
   }
```

`

what is right to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely make this example embedded rather than inherited.  I don't think you should make this call based solely on the fact that objects contain common fields.  Instead, you should use inheritance if it makes sense for your model using standard OO design techniques.  For example, if "myClass is a myBaseClass" doesn't hold true, inheritance is probably the wrong solution.

In general, I'd stay away from classes like `CreatedUpdated` that are just a collection of properties and not an actual object from your domain.  Java/Groovy has only single inheritance, so this only works if you have one base class like this.

Also, for that particular case, created and updated timestamps [can automatically be applied by GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping).  If you're using spring security, check out the [audit-trail plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/audit-trail) for automatically creating `createdBy` and `updatedBy` columns.

Comment: thanks.audit-trail plugin is good.The reason I ask this question is to see not everyone has the attitude that I think

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case audit-trail plugin should suffice the requirements. However if you have such requirement for other fields wherein no plugin is available, then one of the possible solution could be to inject such common fields at compile time via [AST Transformation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations). Internally audit-trail plugin uses this concept to inject those fields. Depending upon your requirement you can either use Global AST Transformations or Local AST Transformations.